# saving Google maps location into Mysql DB

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps

I have such code for insert location and mark it on google maps:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
  <script>
var geocoder;
var map;
function initialize() {
 geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
 var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(52.243240, 21.030295);
var mapOptions = {
 zoom: 8,
 center: latlng
 }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
}

function codeAddress() {
  var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
 geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
  map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: results[0].geometry.location

  }); 


  var input = results[0].geometry.location; 

      document.getElementById("wypisz").innerHTML=input;    

//document.getElementById("wypisz").innerHTML = results[0].geometry.location.lng;


 } else {
   alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
 }
});
  }


 google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);


 //  document.write(position);

</script>
```

In this 2 lines I obtain my coordinates of location "(52.1553949, 21.07453620000001)" for example and display it on page:

```
    var input = results[0].geometry.location; 
document.getElementById("wypisz").innerHTML=input;
```

What I can't do is to split string "input" on 2 substrings (lat and lng), and save it to Mysql DB, into table with lat and lng (both float types).

Comment: What is the question? You want to know how to split "(52.1553949, 21.07453620000001)" and save it into the DB?

Comment: Is it not just `input.split(',');`

Comment: Yes, exactly. I tried at least to split it, but couldn't display effect of this split on page.

Comment: Why would you want to display it? You said you want to save it.

Comment: I ,ve tried this method (input.spilt(',');)

Comment: but unsuccesfull, and bigger problem is how to save it into DB ?

Comment: Yes I want to save in DB, but I also display it on page to see if it works

Comment: There is no need to split it. `input` is of type `LatLng` and you can just call `input.lat()` and `input.lng()` to get values which should be saved.

Comment: thx Anto, it works fine, But how to convert this varaibles (js) into php ?